# Upgrading from AEM 6.1 to 6.3 is failing - org.apache.sling.rewriter.Transformer

Tags: aem

I am trying an inplace upgrade from 6.1 to 6.3. I replaced the 6.1 jar with 6.3 and performed 3 steps.

1. unpack the jar --- SUCCESS

> java -Xmx4096m -jar
>   aem-quickstart-6.3.0.jar -unpack migrate the datastore to the new
>   version --SUCCESS java -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -jar
>   aem-quickstart-6.3.0.jar -v -x crx2oak -xargs -- --load-profile
>   segment-fds
>   --src-datastore=......./author/crx-quickstart/repository/repository/datastore

2. Perform the upgrade -- FAILING I THINK

> java -server -Xmx4096m
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/*/../tmp -Dsling.run.modes=author,dev,crx3,crx3tar -jar crx-quickstart/app/cq-quickstart-6.3.0-standalone-quickstart.jar start
>   -c crx-quickstart -i launchpad -p 4552 -Dsling.properties=conf/sling.properties

The felix console bundles all are active except for the ACS Commons bundle. I read online that we need a 3.X version for that but whenever I hit any page other than /system/console/bundles, they result in a 500 error with a message in the logs that say

> "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to get component of class
>   'interface org.apache.sling.rewriter.Transformer' with type
>   'versioned-clientlibs'."

I wanted to upload the new 3.X version for acs-commons but I am unable to reach the `/crx/packmgr` .

I am not sure if I am missing any steps for the upgrade process. Kindly provide your insights.

Comment: If your issue is just with acs commons, go system/console/bundles and stop the acs commons bundle. If that does not work, find the versioned clientlib component in /system/console/components and stop it. To install the new acs package, you can drop the package under path crx-quickstart/install if it does not exists , create it then restart.

Comment: Like Ahmed says you can install a package by adding to to the install folder on the file system. If it still doesn't work, you can use Curl to delete the rewriter config nodes from command line. If you can start over then try the following. On your 6.1 instance, look for the sling re writer pipeline config that includes 'versioned-clientlibs' or other ACS commons based transformers and do one of the following things
 Delete it from the configuration or
 Disable it by setting enabled to false or
 Make it optional by setting component-optional property to true.
Then do the in-place upgrade.